# How can I mock external function that is used in class method?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I want to mock a function that is used in some method. This function is located in other module.

How can I do that?

Tried this option, but it does not work.

```py
from pack import utils
from pack.another_pack import SomeClass

@pytest.mark.parametrize('attr', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
def test_foo_bar(attr, monkeypatch):
    def mock_return():
        return attr
    monkeypatch.setattr(utils, 'my_function', mock_return)
    SomeClass().foo()  # this foo() function uses my_function inside that I want to mock
```

I want `SomeClass().foo()` to execute my `mock_return()` inside instead of `my_function()`.

Comment: Use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) or the [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) plugin with the `mocker` fixture.

### Your package

`pack/another_pack.py`:

```
from pack import utils

class SomeClass:
    def foo(self):
        return utils.my_function()
```

`pack/utils.py`:

```
def my_function():
    return 'original'
```

### Tests

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
from pack.another_pack import SomeClass


# Replace my_function with another function. You could pass parameters
# to the mocked function and handle them in the replacement.
@pytest.mark.parametrize("attr", ["a", "b", "c"])
def test_replace(attr):
    def mock_return():
        return attr

    with patch("pack.another_pack.utils.my_function", new=mock_return):
        assert SomeClass().foo() == attr


# If you just want to override the return value.
@pytest.mark.parametrize("attr", ["a", "b", "c"])
def test_return_value(attr):
    with patch("pack.another_pack.utils.my_function") as my_func:
        my_func.return_value = attr
        assert SomeClass().foo() == attr


# With the pytest-mock plugin and the mocker fixture instead of unittest.mock.
@pytest.mark.parametrize("attr", ["a", "b", "c"])
def test_mock_plugin(attr, mocker):
    my_func = mocker.patch("pack.another_pack.utils.my_function")
    my_func.return_value = attr
    assert SomeClass().foo() == attr
```

Note that in all tests the first argument of `patch` is the name of the module where you want to mock the function (`pack.another_pack`) with the name of the function how it appears in the module (`utils.my_function`).

`my_function` is mocked for the entire `pack.another_pack` module.

Comment: You helped me a lot in understanding of mocks. Thank you a lot!